# How to ssh into remote linux server using username / ip address and password from window using shell script?

Tags: bash, ssh, git-bash

What I am trying to do is to login to remote Linux server using SSH from my Windows machine by running a shell script via git bash.

I would like to write a script which will be used by an user with basic IT knowledge. This script will execute a bunch of commands on the remote machine, so it does need to establish a SSH connection.

What I have tried to write in this script so far is:
`ssh username@ip <password>`

Comment: [how-can-i-execute-local-script-on-remote-machine-and-include-arguments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87405/how-can-i-execute-local-script-on-remote-machine-and-include-arguments)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: <strike>You should consider installing Jenkins on the remote system.</strike>

Running a command on a remote system can be done via:

```
ssh user@host command arg1 arg2
```

If you omit the password, a password prompt will appear, to get around the password prompt, you should consider setting passwordless SSH login. https://askubuntu.com/questions/46930/how-can-i-set-up-password-less-ssh-login

Comment: this is not an option for me.

Answer (score 0):

Rephrasing what you said, you want to write a script (namely script1.sh) which does the following (in this order):

- Start a ssh connection with a remote
- Execute some commands, possibly written in another script (namely script2.sh)
- Close the connection / Keep it open for additional command line commands

If you want to put the remote commands on script2.sh instead of listing them in script1.sh, you need to consider that script2.sh **must** be on the remote server. If not, then you may consider to delegate to script1.sh the creation/copy of script2.sh on the remote machine. You may copy it in a temporary folder.

In this case, my suggestion is to write script1.sh as follows:

- Copy of script2.sh with

  `scp /path/to/local/script2.sh user@host:/path/to/remote/script2.sh`
- Switch bash sheel to remote shell with

  `ssh user@host`
- Execution of script2.sh

  `sh /path/to/remote/script2.sh`

Instead, if you prefer to list everything in just one script file, you may want to write:

- Switch bash sheel to remote shell with

  `ssh user@host`
- Execution of commands

  `echo "This command has been executed on the remote server"`

  `echo "This command has also been executed on the remote server"`

  ..
- Possibly closing the SSH connection to prevent that the user execute additional commands

You may consider to copy the ssh-keys on the remote server so to avoid password prompts. More information [here](https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/copy-id).